# Drawing on the screen

Tags: c++, windows, drawing

I'm currently developing an application with OpenCV to do visual recognition of elements on the screen.

While a visual representation of the process is not needed, it would be very useful for debugging purposes if I could find a way to draw circles, lines and possibly text directly on the screen, without having an app window.

There are certain applications that, for instance, draw HUDs over the screen. How do they go about doing that?

I need a way for my drawing to always be at the front. In general, all the ways I managed to find involve painting on a window (WinAPI, Direct2D, OpenGL). Is there a workaround to make it appear like it's simply a layover on the desktop (including all open windows)?

Comment: No, but the window can be with size of screen on top of others and partially transparent.

Comment: why was this question voted down? wtf, it's a legitimate question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for the purpose of debugging, just literally draw on the screen. IIRC `GetDC(0)` will get you a device context for the screen, but check out that whole family of functions. in Windows 7 it doesn't even foul up other applications' displays, and reportedly it's likewise "safe" on the mac.

---

for example, this draws an ellipse in the upper left of the screen:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HDC const dc = GetDC( 0 );
    Ellipse( dc, 10, 10, 200, 200 );
}
```

the graphic disappears if it's on top of a window and that window is moved.

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I need. Does the graphic reappear after moving?

Comment: i've not seen the graphics reappear. i think what's going on in windows 7 is that the newfangled DWM (Desktop Window Manager) is intercepting the output so that it doesn't *really* draw directly on the screen, but just in a bitmap that belongs to your app. but i'm not sure. anyway, works ok for just presenting things! :-)

Comment: Never mind, it works! Seeing how it's for debugging, I think the limitations won't be a problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the device context (DC) of the screen, and draw in that DC as usual. The output will be directed to the screen. To achieve that, call WinApi `GetDC("DISPLAY")`, if i'm not mistaken.